# What is the best way to set up nested tests using mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am currently working on some tests, and I'd like to create some structure where I can logically nest my system tests.

Let's imagine I want to run the following tests :

- user registers

  - with invalid data

    - it should fail
  - with valid data

    - it should succeed
    - user logs in

      - with invalid credentials

        - it should fail
      - with valid credentials

        - it should succeed
        - user lists stuff

          - no stuff is available

            - it should return empty list
          - stuff is available

            - it should return a list of stuff
            - user adds stuff to his cart

              - cart should show stuff

... and so on.

Looking at this, this could become a nasty mess of nested 'describe' and 'it'.

What would be the best way to write these tests without having a huge file containing the nested describes ?

(One of ideas was to use dependency injection - awilix - to create scopes and then trickle down the stuff like tokens, product lists, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some *best way to do*, what certainly matters is the **readability** and **maintainability** of your tests.

My approach is rather subjective but I would keep the tests as flattened as possible, by using hooks if needed.

For instance, the register and login tests would be rewritten as the following:

- Register user

  - it should succeed (test case#1)
  - ...
  - it should succeed (test case#n)
  - it should fail (test case#1)
  - ...
  - it should fail (test case#n)
- Login with registered user

  - Before Each hook - User should be registered
  - it should succeed (test case#1)
  - ...
  - it should succeed (test case#n)
  - it should fail (test case#1)
  - ...
  - it should fail (test case#n)
- ...

Comment: Thanks @MuratK, this is a pretty good approach. I am trying to make sure the state of the system generated by the previous tests is always consistent. For example, if I changed the login information, I'd rather avoid having to change my other tests, as they are not related to the login specifically. This is specifically a case of maintainability I am focusing on right now.

Comment: @Simon Guerout I understand your point of view. Be also aware that all your test logic seems to be dependant on the fact that the user gets logged in. If, for some reason, you want to test actions for unlogged users, you can't add them in your dependancy tree. At each nested step you reduce the scope of test possibilies you could write. By using hooks, you could just add or remove them.

Comment: You pointed some really interesting concept : scope. This is pretty much my biggest focus, as what defines the actual order of the tests is the availability of a given scope. I have a good lead on something, will post a gist if it works out!